# clusterssh --action htop - "Error opening terminal: unknown."

Tags: terminal, cluster-ssh

I'd like to run htop on a few hosts, using clusterssh. I haven't changed any defaults in .clusterssh/config.

This works fine:

```
$ clusterssh somehosts -a uptime
...
12:11:30 up 8 days,  4:42,  1 user,  load average: 2.04, 1.74, 1.71
```

This doesn't:

```
$ clusterssh somehosts -a htop
...
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

If I run without an action, TERM is set:

```
$ clusterssh somehosts
...
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Can anyone point me toward useful info on this? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not beautiful, but it works:

```shell
clusterssh somehosts -a 'export TERM=xterm-256color && htop'
```

or

```shell
cssh somehosts -a 'export TERM=xterm-256color && htop'
```